# free java library for picture type detection (Human, Animal,Face, Body, Portrait, Landscape, ...)

Tags: java, computer-vision

I need a java library to determine which image is a "Human body"; which is a "Human Face"; which is an "Animal"; which is a "Landscape" and so on.
Is there something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are anything so convenient out there. Especially since you have very broad classification here. Human bodies are not all so similar, and neither are faces. Animals especially will be nearly impossible to classify, given how varied such things are. I assume you are looking for libs cause you would prefer not have to make the classifiers yourself?

Maybe someone on github has done something, but most likely you have to do this yourself. I'm sure there are existing databases of pictures of animals, faces and bodies. Write a script to train those images into the categories you need, and you should get some results.